# Proving the maximum number of elements of a set is what it is

Tags: logic, solution-verification

Say I have a set $S \subseteq A$ that satisfies some condition $X$, and I want to maximize $|S|$, or the cardinality of $S$.  If I use an argument along the lines of:

*"All numbers of the form $f(x) \in S$ because if this claim is not true for some $x$, we can simply add/append $f(x)$ to $S$ since it does not contradict $X$ (assuming it actually doesn't contradict $X$)."*

And then claim:

*"Since no other elements of $A$ can be in $S$, this maximizes $|S|$",*

is this logically sound (Assume $X$ describes $S$ in general)?  If not, what would be a logically sound argument?

Comment: Why does proof-verification tag automatically switch over to solution-verification?

Comment: It appears that 'solution-verification' is the target of the tag synonym 'proof-verification'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess it greatly depends on the condition X: if the condition only says something about individual elements, then sure, S will be maximal. Simply use a proof by contradiction on a 'maximal set'. 
But if X says something about S as a whole, then perhaps you could end in local maxima. For example, if you think of X saying that S is a clique in a graph G, you will see that the order in which you add the elements matters.

Comment: Then what would be a logically sound argument in the latter case?

Comment: There is no sound argument in the latter case, since the claim is false. "No more element can be added to S such that X holds" is not equivalent to "|S| is maximal among all sets S which satisfy X".